# Access auto tracking feature detection with python script

Tags: python, scripting, tracking

i'm having some troubles in a script that use the auto detect features function from the tracking layout. The above script return the error:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.clip.detect_features.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Does someone knows how to force a change context to clip tracking?

```
import bpy
import random

scene = bpy.context.scene

bpy.ops.clip.open(directory="/home/lucasa/Vídeos/", files=[{"name":"100_0921.MP4", "name":"100_0921.MP4"}], relative_path=True)
print('video clip imported')

clip = bpy.data.movieclips[0]
print("\nMovie Clip %s" % clip.name)

bpy.ops.clip.detect_features()
print('\nDetect Features')
```

Comment: Maybe the answer is already here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Comment: I don't know which layout you need, but the way described in this link under "Change Area.type" seems what you are searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is years late but I will answer this incase anyone stumbles across this.

In this case you need to force context since the operators require a certain context to execute. To do this for the detect_features method you can do:

```
ctx = bpy.context.copy()
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR':
        ctx['area'] = area
bpy.ops.clip.detect_features(ctx)
```

Comment: If there is no clip editor open on the screen this wont work.  Toggling `context.area = 'CLIP_EDITOR'`, copying context and toggling back, may be a more foolproof way to make a context override.